# How to import a graph structure and make a network of objects based on that graph for simulation in OMNet++

Tags: graph, social-networking, simulation, omnet++

I have a graph which is based on real data,and I want to use its structure to make a network based on that graph in OMNet. Besides I want put OMNet objects as the vertices.

I want to know if it is possible and how?

More Info:Because I need to run a discrete event simulation I found it the best way(if it's possible),however if anybody can suggest a better way I'll be appreciated.(+I have used networkX in python for manipulating and run some algorithms,but as I need simulating,I'm not sure if it's good to use python and simpy or not)

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

There are some examples for topology importing. Using the IDE (see the New Network Wizard in the IDE). Generally you should be able to create the NED files required for OMNeT++ from your topology description files (NED is a text file, so if you know your topology, you can create your converter).